# binding left + right mouse button click to different action from middle button?

Tags: xinput, xev, xte

I want to bind a different action (for example, using xbindkeys) to the simultaneous clicking of my left and right mouse buttons than I get by clicking the middle button. Is this possible?

I have disabled middle button emulation using xinput:

```
xinput set-prop  '15' 'libinput Middle Emulation Enabled' 0
```

(where 15 is the device ID for my mouse)

but xbindkeys does not seem to support actions comprised of two button clicks. For example,

```
"xte 'key a'"
b:1+b:3
```

inserts an **a** even if I just click the right mouse button (button 3 according to xev).

The closest I have come to an answer is [this 2016 post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318555), but based on the current (Ubuntu 18.04LTS) man page for xorg.conf the patch does not seem to have ever been merged into xorg.

I have read about using xmodmap to set button mappings, but I haven't found any reference to it allow the definition of a **new** button code being triggered by simultaneously pressing two buttons.

How can I get this to work?